Second Line indentation in the LOF, document class report, in overleaf
I am trying to indent the second lines in the LOF as illustrated below (same for LOT). I took the picture from another question, but the solution provided there didn't work for my document class. 
This is the document I am working with
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}




\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example Figure with a very long caption that will wrap to the next line and show the indentation of the second line properly.}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Another Example Figure with a very long caption that will wrap to the next line and show the indentation of the second line.}
    \label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Remember to load grahpicx in your MWE

First off, the example is missing graphicx otherwiuse the images does not load.
+1 for remembering to use the MWE images.
Your requested look can be done via
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}
\setlength\cftfigindent{0pt}
\setlength\cftfignumwidth{6em}

(though it does not format how the header should look like)
